# How to read data from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

How to read the data stored in ByteBuffer?

- `setValue()` - gets value "12 10" and is converted into Hexadecimal value and is stored in `String[]` data.
- `write()` - converts data into bytes and stores in `ByteBuffer` `dest`.
- `readBuffer` - How can I read data from `ByteBuffer`?

```java
static String[] data = {};
//value = "12 10";
String setValue(String value) {
    String[] samples = value.split("[ ,\n]+");
    data = new String[samples.length];

    //Generates Hex values
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        samples[i] = "0x"+String.format("%02x", Byte.parseByte(samples[i]));
    //data[i] will have values 0x0c, 0x0a
        data[i] = samples[i];
    }
    System.out.println("data :: " +Arrays.toString(samples));
    return value;
}


void write(int sequenceNumber, ByteBuffer dest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("data[i] in bytes :: "+data[i].getBytes());

            dest.put(data[i].getBytes());           

        }   

    }   

void readBuffer(ByteBuffer destValue)
{
        //How to read the data stored in ByteBuffer?
}
```

Comment: Have you read its documentation?

Comment: This is the input : String dataValue = "12 10";  It is converted in to hexadecimal like 0x0c, 0x0a and it is added to array String[] data , then it is added to ByteBuffer like this dest.put(data[i].getBytes()).  Now I need to write a function that reads the ByteBuffer "dest" and returns the output 0x0c, 0x0a. Can anyone please suggest how can this be done

Answer (score 6):

```
destValue.rewind() 
while (destValue.hasRemaining())
     System.out.println((char)destValue.get());
}
```

Comment: This is just printing out lot of  "0"'s

Comment: extra curly bracket at the end (or missing at the end of the `while` line)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the backing array of a ByteBuffer with `.array()`. If you want to convert it to a String, you'll also need to get the current position, or else you will have a lot of zero-bytes at the end. So you'll end up with code like:

```
new String(buf.array(), 0, buf.position())
```

Edit: Oh, it appears you want the byte values. Those you could either get by calling `Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(buf.array(), 0, buf.position())` or loop `x` from `0` to `buf.position` calling `Integer.toString((int)buf.get(x) & 0xFF, 16)` (to get a 2-digit hex code) and collecting the results in a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: It prints everything in one line as 0x0c0x0a, is it possible to get output as 0x0c, 0x0a. Thanks

Comment: System.out.println( Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(dest.array(), dest.position()))); is returning [48, 120, 48, 99, 48, 120, 48, 97], looks like it is ASCI values. But I want output to be 0x0c, 0x0a. Is there a possibility to get this?

Comment: Yes, which is to loop over the values and call `Integer.toString((int)buf.get(x) & 0xFF, 16)` on each, then `add`ing (possibly with a separator and prefix of ' 0x') into a StringBuilder. Which java version are you targeting?

Comment: Java 1.8.   Now looks like I am doing completely wrong stuff. My main requirement is  "Takes a sequence of byte values in hex format and writes these to the byte stream.
      "01 02 1a" => writes bytes 0x01 0x02 0x1a to the byte stream.
" and I clearly dont understand what needs to be done